# how to extract quoted strings using perl/awk?

Tags: perl, unix, awk

I've a file with 2 lines having key, value pair on each line. "//" is used as comment style.

```
1. key = "string_key_value" //string key
```

How can I extract string_key_value without quotes?

```
2. key =100 //integer value
```

How can I extract 100 from here as an integer?

I've to re-use these values in another unix command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
perl -wlne'print $1 if /key\s*=\s*\"?([^\"; ]+)[\" ;]/' source.cpp
```

It pulls out everything after `key =` and before a closing quote/space/semicolon.  if you've got strings with escaped quotes, this will fail, so this should only be used if you need a quick and dirty solution. If you are parsing production data, log files etc, you should use a module in the `Parse::` family on CPAN, rather than using regular expressions.

> I've to re-use these values in another unix command.

Perhaps you should be defining these values in a central location (like a constants file, or a config file), rather than attempting to parse source code.. it would be far less error-prone (not to mention hacky).

Comment: Personally I think that might be a bit cleaner as `say for //` rather than `print $1 if //`

Comment: It worked great. Just added '?' in the last in the regular expression since it didn't work with few cases. perl -wlne'print $1 if /key\s*=\s*\"?([^\"; ]+)[\" ;]?/'

Answer (score 0):

You can look at "[Gory details of parsing quoted constructs](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.1/pod/perlop.pod#Gory_details_of_parsing_quoted_constructs)". `perldoc` is your friend.

Edit: Sorry, I don't think that's what you're looking for. It still may be worth reading, so I'll leave it there.

This should be closer to what you want:

```
my ($key, $value) = $line =~ /(\S+)\s*=\s*"?(.*)"?/
```

Comment: *A friend in need is a friend indeed!*

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are trying to parse Key/Value pairs and then you should look at answers to this StackOverflow question [Regular expression for parsing name value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168171/regular-expression-for-parsing-name-value-pairs)

or try the solutions from the following links:

- [Google: perl key value pairs parse](http://www.google.com/search?q=perl+key+value+pairs+parse&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)
- [Google: awk key value pairs parse](http://www.google.com/search?q=awk+key+value+pairs+parse&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

or simply split every line by '=' and clean quotes.

Answer (score 0):

if you just have key=value pairs, then simply use awk's `gsub()` to remove the quotes

```
$ echo 'key = "string_key_value"' | awk '{gsub("\042","",$NF);print $NF}'
string_key_value
```

Or if just use the shell (bash)

```
$ string='key = "string_key_value"'
$ IFS="="
$ eval echo \$$#
 "string_key_value"
$ result=$(eval echo \$$#)
$ echo $result
 "string_key_value"
$ echo ${result//\"}
 string_key_value
```