# Convert backslash-delimited string into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, string, associative-array, explode

I have a string like this:

```
key1\value1\key2\value2\key3\value3\key4\value4\key5\value5
```

And I'd like it to be an associative array so that I can do:

```
echo $myArray['key1']; // prints value1
echo $myArray['key3']; // prints value3
//etc...
```

I know I can explode on the backslash, but not sure how to go from there.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using a simple [regex](http://regexp.info/) via [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) and [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) is often the shortest and quickest option:

```
 preg_match_all("/([^\\\\]+)\\\\([^\\\\]+)/", $string, $p);
 $array = array_combine($p[1], $p[2]);
```

Now this is of course a special case. Both *keys* and *values* are separated by a <kbd>\</kbd> backslash, as are all pairs of them. The regex is also a bit lengthier due to the necessary double escaping.

However this scheme can be generalized to other `key:value,`-style strings.

#### Distinct `key:value,` separators

Common variations include <kbd>:</kbd> and <kbd>=</kbd> as key/value separators, and <kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>&</kbd> and others as pair delimiters. The regex becomes rather obvious in such cases (with the `/x` flag for readability):

```
 #                    ↓    ↓    ↓
 preg_match_all("/ ([^:]+) : ([^,]+) /x", $string, $p);
 $array = array_combine($p[1], $p[2]);
```

Which makes it super easy to exchange `:` and `,` for other delimiters.

- Equal signs `=` instead of `:` colons.
- For example `\\t` as pair delimiter (tab-separated key:value lists)
- Classic `&` or `;` as separator between key=value pairs.
- Or just `\\s` spaces or `\\n` newlines even.

#### Allow varying delimiters

You can make it more flexible/forgiving by allowing different delimiters between keys/values/pairs:

```
 #                    ↓      ↓       ↓
 preg_match_all("/ ([^:=]+) [:=]+ ([^,+&]+) /x", $string, $p);
```

Where both `key=value,key2:value2++key3==value3` would work. Which can make sense for more human-friendlinies (AKA non-technical users).

#### Constrain alphanumeric keys

Oftentimes you may want to prohibit anything but classic `key` identifiers. Just use a `\w+` word string pattern to make the regex skip over unwanted occurences:

```
 #                   ↓   ↓    ↓
 preg_match_all("/ (\w+) = ([^,]+) /x", $string, $p);
```

This is the most trivial whitelisting approach. If OTOH you want to *assert*/constrain the whole key/value string beforehand, then craft a separate `preg_match("/^(\w+=[^,]+(,|$))+/", …`

#### Strip spaces or quoting

You can skip a few post-processing steps (such as [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) on keys and values) with a small addition:

```
 preg_match_all("/ \s*([^=]+) \s*=\s* ([^,]+) (?<!\s) /x", $string, $p);
```

Or for instance optional quotes:

```
 preg_match_all("/ \s*([^=]+) \s*=\s* '? ([^,]+) (?<![\s']) /x", $string, $p);
```

#### INI-style extraction

And you can craft a baseline INI-file extraction method:

```
 preg_match_all("/^ \s*(\w+) \s*=\s* ['\"]?(.+?)['\"]? \s* $/xm", $string, $p);
```

Please note that this is just a *crude subset* of common INI schemes.

#### Alternative: [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str)

If you have a `key=value&key2=value2` string already, then [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) works like a charm. But by combining it with [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) can even process varying other delimiters:

```
 #                         ↓↓    ↑↑
 parse_str(strtr($string, ":,", "=&"), $pairs);
```

Which has a couple of **pros and cons** of its own:

- Even shorter than the two-line regex approach.
- Predefines a well-known escaping mechanism, such as `%2F` for special characters).
- Does not permit varying delimiters, or unescaped delimiters within.
- Automatically converts `keys[]=` to arrays, which you may or may not want though.

#### Alternative: `explode` + `foreach`

You'll find many examples of [manual key/value string expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5290361/345031). Though this is often more code. `explode` is somewhat overused in PHP due to optimization assumptions. After profiling often turns out to be slower however due to the manual `foreach` and array collection.

Comment: How would the regex look if you have a string that includes tab jumps like that: key1=value1\tkey2=value2\tkey3=value3 ?

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV More like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168171/regular-expression-for-parsing-name-value-pairs - Albeit there are simpler approaches (replacing `\t` with `&` and then a `str_parse()`, or with a regex `\t(\w+)=(\w+)` or something). Please post a new question however if you have a different source.

Comment: @mario Thanks, I stumbled over parse_str() and use that now: 

// convert tab jumps to & to be able to use query function
`$toURL = str_replace("\t","&",$keysValues);`
// parse as URL
`parse_str($toURL, $data);`
// access keys in array 
`$postid = $data['postid'];`

Answer (score 7):

What about something like this :

```
$str = 'key1\value1\key2\value2\key3\value3\key4\value4\key5\value5';
$list = explode('\\', $str);

$result = array();
for ($i=0 ; $i<count($list) ; $i+=2) {
    $result[ $list[$i] ] = $list[$i+1];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Which would get you :

```
array
  'key1' => string 'value1' (length=6)
  'key2' => string 'value2' (length=6)
  'key3' => string 'value3' (length=6)
  'key4' => string 'value4' (length=6)
  'key5' => string 'value5' (length=6)
```

Basically, here, the idea is to :

- split the string
- which will give you an array such as `'key1', 'value1', 'key2', 'value2', ...`
- and, then, iterate over this list, with a jump of 2, using each time :

  - one element as the key -- the one pointed by `$i`
  - the one just after it as the value -- the one pointed by `$i+1`

Answer (score 0):

I am not that good with RegExp but how about this one line code

```
parse_str(preg_replace("/key(.*?)\\value(.*?)(\\|$)/", "key$1=value$2&", $input_lines), $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Wasim's answer which

1. does not work as posted and
2. of which @mario lists the caveats of its use

can be improved / made more flexible by using a mix of negated character classes and escaped literal backslashes to establish a querystring.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7AkOi))

```
parse_str(preg_replace('/([^\\\\]+)\\\\([^\\\\]+)\\\\?/', '$1=$2&', $string), $output);
var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => 'value2',
  'key3' => 'value3',
  'key4' => 'value4',
  'key5' => 'value5',
)
```

---

Otherwise, you can explode, chunk, and manually assign the elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tIhYv))

```
$result = [];
foreach (array_chunk(explode('\\', $string), 2) as [$key, $val]) {
    $result[$key] = $val;
}
var_export($result);  // same output as snippet above
```

Or a body-less `foreach()` with array destructuring: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/p3mhG))

```
$result = [];
foreach (
    array_chunk(explode('\\', $string), 2)
    as
    [$key, $result[$key]]
);
var_export($result);
```

---

Or use looped `strtok()` calls: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4aGOO))

```
$result = [];
$key = strtok($string, "\\");
while ($key !== false) {
    $result[$key] = strtok("\\");
    $key = strtok("\\");
}
var_export($result);
```