# Explode string with two delimited

Tags: php, explode

I have something like this :

```
$string = "a:3;b:4;c:1;d:9";
```

and I want:

```
$array = ['a'=>3, 'b'=> 4, 'c'=>1, 'd'=>9];
```

Thanks

Comment: Very cool. Can you let us know when you get it?

Comment: Stick to array functions and foreach. learn more php basics bro.

Comment: This almost looks like a serialized string.. just a warning, if you're dealing with serialized strings, stop. Use the proper serialization functions.

Comment: Related/simpler approaches: [PHP Split Delimited String into Key/Value Pairs (Associative Array)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5290342)

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "a:3;b:4;c:1;d:9";

$exploded = explode(";",$string);

$newArr = array();
foreach ($exploded as $single){
   $inner =  explode(":",$single);
   $newArr[$inner[0]] =   $inner[1];
}
```

In the end use `$newArr`;

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire

Comment: I didn't downvoted you buddy. It works but helping with the basics is not productive.

Comment: Try here http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: Stating *that* it works isn't as helpful as explaining / documenting *how*. For all we know OP could already have stumbled across some whacky `explode`/`foreach` code before, but didn't figure out how it behaved.