# Converting a string into a multi-dimensional array with commas and pipes

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Tried searching but nothing was exactly what I was looking for.

I have a string that looks like this:

```
$string = "sku1,2|sku2,5";
```

I would like to convert it into a multi-dimensional array that would end up looking like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku] => sku1
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku] => sku2
            [qty] => 5
        )

)
```

So far I've tried using:

```
explode(',',$string);
```

Which is the right idea but it doesn't account for the pipe delimiter to know when to go to the next array group.

Comment: Are the keys just given or do they come from anywhere? (`sku`, `qty`)

Comment: If you mean the [sku] and [qty] I purposely named it. So your example before you deleted it was right on point just needed an extra to name those keys and should be perfect. However, even if I don't I can access it by [0] and [1]. I just named it to make it more readable friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't even bother with looking for `|` or manually traversing anything. You can generate the desired array already with [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) containing just a few fillers:

```
preg_match_all(
    "/(?<sku>\w+),(?<qty>\d+)\K/",
    $string, $array, PREG_SET_ORDER
);
```

This simply extracts any combination of alphanumeric `\w+` and numeric `\d+` entries delimited by `,` comma.

Comment: The output seems to show more than it's supposed to: [0] => 
[sku] => sku1
[1] => sku1
[qty] => 2
[2] => 2

Comment: @dmotors: Yes, it doubles the keys numerically ("a few fillers"). A regex-approach mostly makes sense to constrain/assert the input further. For other/simpler approaches (such as `parse_str`) see [PHP Split Delimited String into Key/Value Pairs (Associative Array)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5290342)

Comment: Understood. That is not a problem I guess I overlooked what you meant by "a few fillers".

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way, but you have to start with the pipe. So first [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your sting by the pipe, then go through each element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and explode it by the comma.

To get the associative keys, just [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) your exploded array with the keys, which you want, e.g.

```
$array = array_map(function($v){
    return array_combine(["sku", "qty"], explode(",", $v));
}, explode("|", $string));

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution but this should work for you:

```
$string = "sku1,2|sku2,5";

$explodePipe = explode('|', $string);

$resultArray = array();

foreach ($explodePipe as $explodedPipe) {
    $explodeSku = explode(',', $explodedPipe);
    $resultArray[]['sku'] = $explodeSku[0];
    $resultArray[]['qty'] = $explodeSku[1];
}
```