# how to convert a string into an array in php

Tags: php

How to convert a string to an array in PHP? I've a string like this:

```
$str = "php/127/typescript/12/jquery/120/angular/50";
```

The output:

```
Array (
    [php]=> 127
    [typescript]=> 12
    [jquery]=> 120
    [angular]=> 50
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Split Delimited String into Key/Value Pairs (Associative Array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290342/php-split-delimited-string-into-key-value-pairs-associative-array)

Comment: Since this is closed I put a simple PHP way as answer to the one above. Look at `Split into segments and loop thru incrementing by two.`. I was wondering why all are juggling with costly regex, when it is a simple for loop.

Comment: @Markus Zeller i am giving as your comment & result is coming so why i giving down vote insted of up vote?

Comment: @KUMAR I did not see your answer while I was writing mine. Downvote did not come from me. Btw, you need to count() - 1. When you post a faulty answer too quickly you must expect downvotes.

Comment: @MarkusZeller `count() - 1` is not needed or technically correct, the for loop is checking for less than (`<`) not less than or equal (`<=`).

Comment: When count is not even (for example extra slash at the end without a value) and you use $i+1 in the loop, you are out of bounds.

Comment: True, but that is not what the OP has presented as sample data, and this subtraction would be an extra operation to perform uselessly.

Comment: Handling (possible and predictable) errors is a style of good code. A -1 does not cost too much or will over complicate that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_match_all` (Regular Expression), and `array_combine`:

RegEx used : `([^\/]*?)\/(\d+)`, eplanation [here (by RegEx101)](https://regex101.com/r/GrutcI/1)

```
$str = "php/127/typescript/12/jquery/120/angular/50";

#match string
preg_match_all("/([^\/]*?)\/(\d+)/", $str, $match);

#then combine match[1] and match[2] 
$result = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]);

print_r($result);
```

Demo (with steps) : https://3v4l.org/blZhU

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use `preg_match_all` to extract the keys and values from the path separately.  Then, use `array_combine` to build the hashmap:

```
$str = "php/127/typescript/12/jquery/120/angular/50";
preg_match_all("/[^\W\d\/]+/", $str, $keys);
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $str, $vals);
$mapped = array_combine($keys[0], $vals[0]);
print_r($mapped[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => php
    [1] => typescript
    [2] => jquery
    [3] => angular
)
```

Comment: It is very useful.
Thanks for reading and the solution. The code's beauty.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `explode()` with `for()`Loop as below:-

```
<?php
    
    $str = 'php/127/typescript/12/jquery/120/angular/50';
    $list = explode('/', $str);
    $list_count  = count($list);

    $result = array();
    for ($i=0 ; $i<$list_count; $i+=2) {
        $result[ $list[$i] ] = $list[$i+1];
    }
    
    print_r($result);
    ?>
```

**Output:-**

```
 Array
    (
        [php] => 127
        [typescript] => 12
        [jquery] => 120
        [angular] => 50
    )
```

Demo Here :- https://3v4l.org/8PQhd

Comment: note `count($list)` will be evaluated on every single iteration, you should avoid doing this and instead store the count in a variable before the loop.

Comment: ok sir. i edited by answer.

Comment: It is very useful.
Thanks for reading and the solution.

Comment: Not for me, it's still reading `for ($i=0 ; $i<count($list) ; $i+=2) {`, not `$count = count($list); for ($i=0 ; $i<$count ; $i+=2) {`

Comment: sir , i updated my answer , why you down vote?

Comment: @Geoffrey sir i updated my code & output will come , so why you give me down vote?

Comment: 1) How do you know I was the one to downvote? 2) Your answer is wrong still `list_count` should be `$list_count`.

Comment: @Geoffrey Sir in comment you say `Not for me, it's still reading` so what does it means?

Comment: When you stated you had updated the answer, at that time you had not done it yet. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216472/discussion-between-kumar-and-geoffrey).